# mysql query left join or group_concat or?

Tags: mysql

This SQL query has had me stumped on how to do it.

I've got the following 2 mysql tables:

```
    [items]
      id
      title

    [ledger]
      id
      itemid
      qty
      stockcode
```

I'm performing a select from the [items] table where id = 123.I also want to return an 'extras' column in the result set which matches on items.id = ledger.itemid and is a comma separated list of [ledger] stockcodes that have a SUM(qty) > 0 . The sum reflects that an item may have ledger entries showing qty of +5 and -2 images = total of 3 images. The 3 images would be reflected in the extras column as "image,image,image".

```
    select
        id
        ,title
        ,???? as extras
    from
        items
    where
        items.id = 123
```

An example result for the 'extras' column might be:

```
    bold,highlight,border,image,image,image
```

which reflects a result from the ledger table with sum(qty) > 0

```
    bold (1)
    highlight (1)
    border (1)
    image (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a `LEFT JOIN` and a `GROUP_CONCAT` and `HAVING` to get the info you are looking for:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, GROUP_CONCAT( l.stockcode SEPARATOR ',' ) extras
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN ledger l ON i.id = l.itemid
WHERE i.id = 123 
HAVING SUM(l.qty) > 0
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4db68/4)

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT id, title, extras
FROM items
JOIN (
    SELECT itemsid, GROUP_CONCAT(stockcode SEPERATOR ',') extras
    FROM ledger
    GROUP BY itemsid
    HAVING SUM(qty) > 0
) t ON t.itemsid = items.id
WHERE id=123
```

Comment: I've looked at doing it this way but was worried that a subquery on the entire ledger table (which could potentially be huge) might result in performance issues down the track?

Comment: sometimes you just gotta do what you've gotta do. if performance becomes an issue then you may want to consider creating a [materialised view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) of the GROUP_CONCAT query and using that instead

Comment: I've posted another question about using a user defined variable in the subquery - not sure if something along those lines would provide another another possible solution (I haven't really used them before so don't know the limitations) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823288/set-a-mysql-user-variable-per-row