# set a mysql user variable per row?

Tags: mysql

The following SQL statement sets a user variable @id which I'm then using in the trailing subquery. My problem is the @id variable only gets set to the first items.id in the result set - not "per row" - so the result from the subquery is the same for every row in the main select. Does anyone know if there's a way to reset the @id variable for each row??

```
    select
         items.id
        ,items.title
        ,@id := items.id
        ,(
            select
                group_concat(x.y)
            from
                (
                    select
                        group_concat(ledger.stockcode) as y
                    from
                        ledger
                    where
                        @id = ledger.itemid
                    group by
                         ledger.stockcode
                    having
                        sum(ledger.stockqty) > 0
                ) as x
            ) as extras
    from
        items
    where
        items.id = 196
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select
     a.id
    ,a.title
    ,b.y as extras
from
    items a
inner join
    (select
       group_concat(ledger.stockcode) as y
    from
       ledger
    where 
       ledger.itemid = 196
    group by
       ledger.stockcode
    having
       sum(ledger.stockqty) > 0) b
on
    a.id = 196 AND a.id = b.itemid
```